# Log4j2 add asyncLogger programmatically

Tags: java, log4j2

So the question is how to add AsyncLogger dynamically in Java code?

```
<AsyncLogger name="io.example" level="info" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
 </AsyncLogger>
```

I Know that add sync logger programmatically.

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration configuration = context.getConfiguration();
// creating logConfig
configuration.addLogger(packageName, loggerConfig);
```

but I can't find any "async" options. (Not appender) Also, There are not guide in offical page.

Please help!

Comment: Could you please describe why you need to add loggers programmatically? Many times these kinds of questions are an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) and there is a better way to solve the real problem.

Comment: D.B// hello , Because of Using datasource bean. Also, In the future I want to add dynamic logger add page in my webpage